# Using attachFile and Submit

Tags: file-upload, submit

I have the following HTML:

```
     <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        Select a file to upload: 
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="USER_NAME" id="USER_NAME" value="user_name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
```

I'm having a couple of problems.

Firstly, in the entry field (named "file") I want to set the name of the file to upload. I can do that just with WebElement.type(), but I get a warning about using attachFile. I'm happy to use that, but when I do so I get the error:

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

My second problem is that if I set the content of the entry field by type(), the submit button doesn't work. I can get the WebElement by css, but neither click() or submit() works. Nothing happens at all when I do either.

Thanks in advance for any help, and apologies for dumbness.